# Gulp failed to locate@import file nib.style

Tags: javascript, gulp, stylus

I get the following error

```
 failed to locate@import file nib.style
```

when trying to compile by .styl files using `gulp`

Any idea how to fix it?

```
gulp.task('flat', function () {
    gulp.src(['**/*.styl', '!**/**mixins**.styl', '!**/**variables**.styl'])
      .pipe(stylus())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('test/'));
});


{
    "dependencies": {
        "bower": "~1.4.1",
        "gulp": "~3.9.0",
        "gulp-complexity": "~0.3.0",
        "gulp-connect": "~2.2.0",
        "gulp-jscs": "~2.0.0",
        "gulp-jscs-stylish": "~1.1.2",
        "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.2",
        "gulp-sloc": "~1.0.4",
        "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
        "gulp-stylus": "~2.1.1",
        "jshint-stylish": "~2.0.1",
        "open": "~0.0.5",
        "stylus": "~0.52.4",
        "nib": "~1.1.0"
    },
    "name": "app",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `gulp-stylus` to use `nib`:

```
var nib = require('nib')();

...
.pipe(stylus({ use : nib }))
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to import nib on your task:

```
var nib = require( 'nib' );
```

And you also need to tell stylus to use it:

```
gulp.src( [ '**/*.styl', '!**/**mixins**.styl', '!**/**variables**.styl' ] )
  .pipe( stylus( { use: [ nib() ] } ) )
  .pipe( gulp.dest( 'test/' ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue include nib in the gulp file, as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@tplusrex/how-to-setup-nib-with-gulp-f2f9e5269325#.9m8jthkuv).

```
var stylus = require('gulp-stylus');
var nib = require('nib');

gulp.task('flat', function () {
  gulp.src(['themes/**/*.styl', '!themes/**/**mixins**.styl', '!themes/**/**variables**.styl'])
  .pipe(stylus({
    compress: true,
    use: nib()
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('test/'));
});
```